# How can I force the Chrome browser to disable an extension by reloading it too frequently?

Tags: google-chrome

I'm using a managed C720 Chromebook. Developer mode and most things of that nature are disabled. Web filtering is enabled from the "Chromium M" extension. When I restarted my device, the extension was automatically disabled because "This extension reloaded itself too frequently".

Is it possible for me to recreate the circumstances that lead to that happening?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, there is a way:

1) You can try and do developer mode, and keep spamming `CTRL + D + Forward` Button.

2) Login normally, but keep on spamming those buttons, then change to like a guest wifi, or a slow one then `CTRL + SHFT + BACKSPACE`, and delete your history, and that should be it, if it doesnt work the first time it should work the second time.

Comment: They patched this method. Any other way?

Answer (score 0):

1. go to chrome://inspect/#extensions
2. click on inspect under the chromium m extension
3. go to the console tab
4. type close(window)